# Appium cannot find element

Tags: appium

I am trying to find the header of an iOS app in a page-agnostic way. This header is visible on all pages and always found with the following class chain:
    `header_class_chain = '**/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther'`
This class chain runs a global search for all elements of type `XCUIElementTypeOther` that are 14 levels deep. I cannot search by accessibility_id because those tags do not exist, nor do I expect them to be added anytime soon.

In the Appium Inspector, when I search on the above class chain using `self.driver.find_element((MobileBy.IOS_CLASS_CHAIN, header_class_chain))`, I always find the header element I want, whether I am on a page directly accessed from the in-app menu or on some child page. Thus, I assumed I could use that class chain to find the header regardless of page content.

However, when I run a test script under automation, searching on that class chain finds the header ONLY on pages that are directly accessible via the menu. I expect this class chain to function under automation the same way that it functions manually, that is, it finds the header on any displayed page.

Two interesting observations that may or may not help. First, the header's element ID as reported by Appium does not change while the app is in a given workflow. That is, if I were to progress through the purchase workflow, the header's ID in Appium remains constant until I either finish the workflow or I navigate to another page via the menu. I have observed this behavior both manually through the Appium Inspector and in logs from automated test runs.

Second, while searching for the header on a child page, I saw the following lines in the Appium logs:
`[WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\n  \"value\" : false,\n  \"sessionId\" : \"4C72B56A-C6C6-4D9A-850E-3C95EE014E29\",\n  \"status\" : 0\n}"
[WD Proxy] Replacing sessionId 4C72B56A-C6C6-4D9A-850E-3C95EE014E29 with 3a91c7cb-d660-48b4-8b2d-144dbaecfaae`
When I started my test, the logs reported `[info] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Session created with session id: 3a91c7cb-d660-48b4-8b2d-144dbaecfaae`.
Shortly after, another sessionId was introduced to my test run: `[debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 200: {"value":{"sessionId":"4C72B56A-C6C6-4D9A-850E-3C95EE014E29","capabilities":{"device":"iphone","browserName":"APPNAME","sdkVersion":"12.1","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.COMPANY.APPNAME"}},"sessionId":"4C72B56A-C6C6-4D9A-850E-3C95EE014E29","status":0}` (app name redacted, as app is not yet publicly available.)
I am not familiar enough with Appium to rule out the possibility that these 2 sessionIds is what's causing my search to fail. If I were to guess, I would say the base driver running the app carries the sessionId starting with 3a91 and the WebDriverAgent is assigned the 4C72 sessionID and that the WebDriverAgent somehow interacts with the base driver. Again, this is just an educated guess and is likely tangential to my real problem: Appium not finding a header element where I clearly expect it to.

Why is this call succeeding manually, but failing under automation?
How could I change my code so that I can find the header, regardless of what page I'm on?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was searching on the wrong element. On pages directly accessible from the menu, the header is 14 levels of `XCUIElementTypeOther` deep. On child pages, the header is 15 levels deep. I must modify my search to find a header that is visible at either 14 or 15 levels deep.